# How to show a selected file preview in a pop up window

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

How to show the uploaded file preview in a popup window? i just wanted to do it in angular 8.. Now the preview is showing when the preview button clicks. ..

```
preview() {
        // Show preview 
        var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
        if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
            return;
        }

    }
    previewFile() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
        reader.onload = (_event) => {
            this.previewUrl = reader.result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: edit your question with error code i want to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component has 3 variables and one event named `preview`. The variable `message` is used to show the validation error message and `imgURL` will have the uploaded image URL to be previewed.

The `preview` event first checks for uploaded file reference. If there are no files to upload, it simply returns. It also validates the mime type of the uploaded file as only images are allowed to be uploaded.

Next, it creates an object of `FileReader`. The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files stored on the user’s computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read. The `readAsDataURL` method starts reading the contents of the specified file and, once finished, the result attribute contains `URL` represents the file’s data.

The `reader.onload` event is triggered once the reading operation is successfully completed. Inside the load event, `imgURL` value is set to the result returned by the `fileReader` object.

**TS**

```
public imagePath;
  imgURL: any;
  public message: string;

  preview(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
      this.imgURL = reader.result; 
    }
  }
```

The file upload control has an attribute called `accept` with the value set to **“Image/*”**. The accept attribute specifies the types of files that the server accepts (that can be submitted through a file upload) and this attribute can only be used with `<input type=”file”>`.

The `src` attribute of the image tag is set to `imgURL` property defined in the component.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Angular 8 Image Preview before Upload:</h3>
<span style="color:red;" *ngIf="message">{{message}}</span>
<input #file type="file" accept='image/*' (change)="preview(file.files)" />
<img [src]="imgURL" height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
```

and Second Option is that for displaying the image that means if no image upload then default image will be show like this

Simply Add this line

```
<img [src]="imgURL || 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSR2EkcTCrrdW1cyriPIgrCzaB8X3B0Mp1lXkFgSoX5n0gh9x40dA&s'" height="200" > <!-- This example is for displaying placeholder image if no image found -->
```

you can preview or [Edit Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2wxup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

> SECOND OPTION

And For To display in popUp you need to install some dependency for bootstrap

First install ngx-bootstrap npm module using below CLI command.

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap
```

Now import ngx-bootstap module in your root module like this :

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ]
});
```

After Installing this CDN import into **index.html**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Than import that module in your ts file and use it like this :

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

And in angular 8 `@ViewChild` need 2 argument

```
@ViewChild('myModel',{static: false}) myModel: ModalDirective;

// Now use this code to when you want open model :
this.myModel.show();

// Now use this code to when you want hide model :
this.myModel.hide();
```

And this is PopUp Modal

**HTML**

```
<!-- POPUP FOR IMAGE PREVIEW --> 
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #myModel="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">  
          <span class="hide" (click)="hide()">&times;</span> 
        <div class="modal-body">     
          <div class="text-center">
           <img [src]="imgURL" height="200">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<!-- POPUP FOR IMAGE PREVIEW -->
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('myModel',{static: false}) myModel: ModalDirective;

  public imagePath;
  imgURL: any;
  public message: string;

  preview(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
      this.imgURL = reader.result; 
      this.myModel.show();
    }
  }

  hide(){
    this.myModel.hide();
  }
```

Here is Your Example with popUP [With PopUp](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewcdqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

> **SOLUTION FOR DOWNLOAD IMAGE**

And For Preview Image Download You need to install dependency i.e `npm i file-saver`

after that pass the file event to download function when download funtion call we take file from event and store into one variable for example

```
download(files){
  var previewImage = files[0];
  FileSaver.saveAs(previewImage);
}
```

and import the file-save dependency where u implement ur preview

```
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
```

and this is `modal-footer` for download and cancel button

```
<div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="download(file.files)">Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="hide()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

Here is complete solution [Check It here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewcdqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This i have already done.. u also showing preview but thats not in popup .. i just want to show it in popup window

Comment: @neethu wait few min i m implementing

Comment: what is the ModalModule here? im getting this exception when i tried this Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'ModalModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: @neethu vijayan have you install `npm install ngx-bootstrap` after install this dependency you need to import under **app.module.ts** `import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';` and put under `import: [ ModalModule.forRoot() ]` and also import `import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';` this **`ModalDirective`** where your modal is showing and if not understand then read my answer again carefully if not then comment me

Comment: @ kiran Mistry after importing also  i am getting that same exception

Comment: try to re-run project

Comment: Hi its working now.. Thank u so much.. I have one more doubt .. How to add two buttons called cancel and download in that popup

Comment: hello @neethu vijayan ty for ur rply plz...mark and vote up my answer so other developer can find solution easily

Comment: neethu vijayan wait i m implementing

Comment: @ Kiran Mistry Ok.. I want to preview doc, pdf everythng i tried this but preview is coming only for images and for pdf it is blank..

Comment: hello neethu Vijayan i edit my answer plzz have a look...and..for pdf you have to install `pdf-viewer` dependency for showing only pdf into your application

Comment: Hi i have tried this and it is working perfectly... Thank you so much for your time..

Comment: @neethu vijayan welc☻me

Comment: Hi.. Is it possible to upload not only image also doc , pdf ? I have added ngx-doc-viewer dependency but it doesnt work

Comment: Hello @neethu vijayan yes you can do it with the help of this `accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .jpe, .jfif, .jif"` for example `<input type="file" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .doc" >` and you not vote up my answer plz voteup and ty...happy coding☻

Comment: yea sure.. i have tried with ngx-pdf-viewer so now pdf is upporting but word doc is still not able to preview